# How to access an array in an array in a collection

Tags: angular, typescript

`component :-

*ngFor="let ind of industryService.industries"  value="{{ind.field[1].fieldName}}"`

How access fieldName in this collection object [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52vCK.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: @VLAZ it's printing [object object]

Comment: You just want to show the first element so you should write ```[value]="ind.field[0].field_id.fieldName"```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Emilien you are correct :-)

Comment: @Govi-BoySL Let me post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do that, you will need to go deeper throught your object :

```
[value]="ind.field[0].field_id.fieldName"
```

And if you want to ngFor of `field` :

```
<div *ngFor="let ind of industryService.industries; let i = index" [value]="ind.field[index].field_id.fieldName">
  <div *ngFor="let fieldItem of ind.field>
    <p>{{ fieldItem.fieldName }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey can I get all fieldNames in the field array object? how?

Comment: You will have to ngFor of field. Maybe try something like :
```ts
<div *ngFor="let ind of industryService.industries" [value]="ind.field[0].field_id.fieldName">
  <div *ngFor="let item of ind.field">
  <p>{{ item.fieldName }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```